# Find if any of a list of substrings is present in a string

Tags: excel, excel-formula, find, substring

My problem is that I have a long list of titles that need to be categorised based on keywords. There are 10 categories, that each have between 2 and 16 keywords.

I created a table to do the analysis in like so:

| Title | cat 1 | cat 2 | etc. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| How to foo the bar |  |  |  |
| Wax on, wax off |  |  |  |

Now I want to fill the table with `1`'s and `0`'s based on the fact if the title contains a keyword or not. I have the keywords and categories stored in a separate table like so:

| cat 1 | cat 2 | cat 3 | etc. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| foo | on | how |  |
| bar | off |  |  |
| wax |  |  |  |

I managed to find a formula that works, but it only works if there are **no empty cells** in the category range. Otherwise it will always find a match.

The formula I use is:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH([cat 1 2:4];[Title A2])))))>0;1;0)
```

Where the parts between `[]` is pseudocode ofcourse.

Is there a way to adapt the formula so that I can use an oversized range for the categories, so that I don't have to adjust them for each and every category?

Comment: What version of Excel have you got? Also, are you not worried about substring being part of a larger substring"e.g. foo being part of food, ultimately returning false positives?

Comment: @JvdV version 16.44 (for Mac)

Comment: So not worried about false positives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=--(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F$2:INDEX(F:F,COUNTA(F:F)),$A2)))>0)
```

This does not account for possible false positive when a substring is found in a larger substring.